# How to receive multiple location events in Android

Tags: android, location

In my application i want to receive location updates of different distances from the set point.
In the main activity i have several objects, and each object needs to get location event on some distance from its set point.

I hope i'm clear.

I tried the function **requestLocationUpdates** with its listener, but in case of several sequential requests, it fires the event only from the closest distance request.

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.FUSED_PROVIDER, 0, 1000, locationListener);
```

Is there any way to do what i want ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what you are asking but it sounds like the new Awareness API might help. https://developers.google.com/awareness/

It allows you to combine location with other pieces of information and only get call backs when they all occur.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is not exactly what i need.

Comment: The Awareness allows combine several sensors together to single event. What i need is that each object could set its location event on distance change from some initial point.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you need to receive updates when the device is at different specified distances from a certain point (lat-lng). If so, you may create [LocationFences](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/fence/LocationFence) with radius set to your distances and register using Awareness [Fence API](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/fence-api-overview). When you receive the fence callbacks, you can call the getLocation() snapshot to get the actual location and use that to update your app.

I hope I've interpreted your question correctly.